# File check for IP change

Tags: linux, scripting, ip

I need to update a file which contain my external ip address on a server via scp.
Before updating the file I want to ensure that it contain an actual IP address else it must not be updated on the server.

My cron script that check for my IP often result in garbage error result.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Can you show rhe script you run to check if the file contains an IP, and the results you get so far?

Comment: curl icanhazip.com > ip-location1.txt

Comment: result is an ip address in a file name  ip-location1.txt

Comment: when there is an error i get this instead <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Application Error</title> <style media="screen"> html,body,iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; } html,body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; } iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0; } </style> </head> <body>

Comment: I do not have any script to check the file for ip, I am looking for one

Comment: python seems nice to check if string is an IP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462784/check-if-a-string-matches-an-ip-address-pattern-in-python this package: https://pypi.org/project/IPy/

Answer (score 0):

If you're currently using

```
curl icanhazip.com > ip-location1.txt
```

then by adding the `-f` option you can make `curl` return an error (and no output) if the webserver does, and so there hopefully won't be a need to figure out whether the output is an IP address or a HTML error message.

```
curl -f icanhazip.com > ip-location1.txt
```

With a bit more complexity, you can add a retry feature:

```
for i in 1 2 3   # if you want more retries, add more numbers here
do
    curl -f icanhazip.com > ip-location1.txt
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ -s ip-location1.txt ]
    then
        break
    fi
    # if we get here, the current attempt failed
    sleep 5  # be nice and wait a bit before retrying instead of spamming the service
done
if [ ! -s ip-location1.txt ]
then
    echo "i cannot haz ip."
    # do whatever you want to do in case of all the retries fail
fi
```

Comment: thanks, this solution help. file still result blank if no ip at moment of check. Im looking for a way to check this file for a new IP changed from previous known IP before uploading via scp

so that it check and confirm that the file possess an IP address